# Apply global changes on UIDatePicker and UITableView in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm working with SwiftUI at the moment and since I'm supporting dark mode I've declared a color set to which my view has to conform if it's in light/dark mode.

This of course requires a lot of changes in every component and right now I have a lot of Views that has this code in it

```
init() {
    // Make Dividers the same color as the background to make them disappear
    UITableView.appearance().separatorColor = UIColor(named: "background")
    // Set List background color
    UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "background")
    UIPickerView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "background")
}
```

I've tried extending single components but I must be doing something wrong, I've also tried to extend View but build is failing every time, is there a way to declare it in just one file and make it a global change so that I can clear all this redundant code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually a pretty easy question from what I can see but I've not been around a lot in the iOS world so...

The solution is to put all that code in the AppDelegate file, specifically in

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool
```